# Blender Python String manipulation

Tags: python, string, blender

How do you remove all characters except the array of float values and sepparators(,)?

`<Color (r=0.65, g=0.54, b=0.43)>`

Into this: 0.65, 0.54, 0.43

Comment: Color looks like it might be a class object in which case you could get the values directly by referencing the attributes. `acolor = Color()` then `[acolor.r, acolor.g, acolor.b]`

Answer (score 0):

using regexps:

```
import re
nre = re.compile(r'*.(0\.\d\d).*(0\.\d\d).*(0\.\d\d)')
m = nre.match('<Color (r=0.65, g=0.54, b=0.43)>')
print(' ,'.join(m.groups()))
==> 0.65 ,0.54 ,0.43
```